# How to install a service programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am having a Form : InstallerForm.cs

```
public partial class InstallerForm : Form
{
  private void InstallerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   //Check if service is installed
   ServiceInstaller.ServiceIsInstalled("MyServiceName");
  }
}

public class ServiceInstaller
{
 private const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
 private const int SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010;

 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 private class SERVICE_STATUS
 {
  public int dwServiceType = 0;
  public ServiceState dwCurrentState = 0;
  public int dwControlsAccepted = 0;
  public int dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
  public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
  public int dwCheckPoint = 0;
  public int dwWaitHint = 0;
 }

 [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerA")]
 private static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(ServiceManagerRights dwDesiredAccess);
  
 public static bool ServiceIsInstalled(string ServiceName)
 {
     IntPtr scman = OpenSCManager(ServiceManagerRights.Connect);
      try
      {
         IntPtr service = OpenService(scman, ServiceName,
         ServiceRights.QueryStatus);
         if (service == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
         CloseServiceHandle(service);
          return true;
       }
       finally
       {
          CloseServiceHandle(scman);
        }
   }
}
  [Flags]
  public enum ServiceManagerRights
    {
        Connect = 0x0001,
        CreateService = 0x0002,
        EnumerateService = 0x0004,
        Lock = 0x0008,
        QueryLockStatus = 0x0010,
        ModifyBootConfig = 0x0020,
        StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
        AllAccess = (StandardRightsRequired | Connect | CreateService |
        EnumerateService | Lock | QueryLockStatus | ModifyBootConfig)
    }
```

This is my initial code to check MyService is installed or not. But on this point

```
IntPtr scman = OpenSCManager(ServiceManagerRights.Connect);
```

I am getting an Exception like "System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.' "

Is it because of the [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
can i get any assistance on this??

Comment: *Extremely* high odds that you have an incorrect P/Invoke definition. That is a sure-fire way to corrupt memory, which will result in an AccessViolationException. Please [edit] your question to include the actual code that you're using, along with the error stack-trace. (Also, why have you tagged this [[tag:asp.net]]? It does not make sense to use ASP.NET, a web framework, in a Windows service.)

Comment: @CodyGray _"It does not make sense to use ASP.NET, a web framework, in a Windows service"_ ...unless you're self-hosting via OWIN or something. But yeah it's probably unlikely.

Comment: Granted, I've never heard of OWIN, and web stuff is not my area of expertise, but I don't see why you'd need it there, either, @ADyson. The vast majority of the time, when programmers reach for a service, they should just be creating a standard "headless" Windows application instead. That can run in the background, displaying no UI, but is not subject to any of the limitations of services.

Comment: @CodyGray To give an example, I use Quartz.NET, a task scheduler. It runs as a windows service. It also has a web interface written in ASP.NET called Quartzmin, which allows you to configure the scheduler easily. The web UI can be run from within the same windows service as the scheduler (which is otherwise headless, as you mention) using OWIN self-hosting, so that a) it can easily interact with the scheduler's processes, and b) you don't have to have a separate webserver installed on the server. It's pretty neat, and an obvious use case IMHO.

Comment: @CodyGray If you're interested... https://medium.com/@singhsukhpinder/self-hosting-net-application-using-owin-framework-960c01ff8d83  (and https://github.com/jlucansky/Quartzmin for the specific example I mentioned). In .NET Core / 5 of course, (as I understand it) all web apps are effectively hosted in a console or service application anyway using the hostbuilder, so this is the way the world has gone. e.g. ASP.NET Core doesn't require IIS anymore, it can run its own webserver. OWIN was just the .NET Framework forerunner to it really.

Comment: @CodyGray it's actually *common* to host ASP.NET Core as a service, eg in a container, as a standalone on top of Kestrel. Microservices are typically standalone, often packaged in containers.  In-process IIS hosting is a relative late-comer. Before that ASP.NET Core apps were standalone. Many C# and ASP.NET Core's features were added to make it easier to create small standalone services, eg top-level methods, endpoint routing, worker services and the Worker template. Right now you can host an ASP.NET Core CLI app with a single `UseWindowsService()` or `UseSystemd()` call

Comment: @fia you don't need Interop to install a service. Classes (actually, components you can drop on a form)  to install services and control services through Windows Forms are available since 2002.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is there any alternate way to do this?. Actually my requirement is: i'm already having an .exe file which i need to Install/Uninstall/Start/Stop programmatically with its link.

Comment: Yes, since 2002. It's a component named `Service`something in the Toolbox

Comment: Found it - services can be created using the [ServiceBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase?view=netframework-4.8) component, installed/updated through the [ServiceInstaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller?view=netframework-4.8) component

Comment: Creating services in .NET Framework is covered in the [Develop Windows service apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/) section, with a [How To](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-create-windows-services) section that shows how to perform various tasks, including how to [control services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-start-services) through the ServiceController class